# How to spawn a new process in php to call a node script that requires a child process

Tags: php, node.js, symfony

I'm trying to run a **PHP** code in isolation. The php code simply calls a node script at intervals with required arguments. The **Node.js** script on the other hand computes the arguments to get additional data from **mongoDb** and then spawns a child process within it to call **Phantomjs** with those arguments and creates heatmap image file(s).

Now the Node.js script runs fine when fired from command line with the right arguments.

But no matter what I try I'm unable to get it to work when called from php.

I have tried shell_exec and exec like below:

```
$node = '/usr/local/bin/node';
$scriptPath = $this->basePath . '/web/scripts/node/heatmaps_node_wrapper.js';
$clickmapCmd = $node . ' ' . $scriptPath . ' ' . $url . ' ' . $groupId . ' ' . $heatmapId . ' click';
$mousemovemapCmd = $node . ' ' . $scriptPath . ' ' . $url . ' ' . $groupId . ' ' . $heatmapId . ' mousemove';
$asyncCmd = ' >' . $this->basePath . '/logs/heatmap.io.log 2>'. $this->basePath . '/logs/heatmap.err.log &';

exec($clickmapCmd . $asyncCmd);
exec($mousemovemapCmd . $asyncCmd);
```

also tried using symfony's ProcessBuilder Component, like so -

```
$builder = new ProcessBuilder();
$builder->setPrefix('/usr/local/bin/node');
$builder->setArguments(array($scriptPath, $url, $groupId, $heatmapId, 'click'));
$process = $builder->getProcess();
$process->setTimeout(1000);
$process->setIdleTimeout(1000);
$process->start();
$output = $process->getOutput();
```

Both fail to create the heatmap images.

But debugging the symfony code and studying symfony's **Process** object helped me discover the likely problem. In the objects stderr I see the following message -

```
events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: spawn phantomjs ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
at child_process.js:1144:20
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

So my guess is the problem is with Node trying to create a child process of, of PHP's child process(??).

So my question is, what is the solution (or work around) to this problem??

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that node can't find `phantomjs`. If it's not in the `$PATH` for the user executing the node script, you may try using the full path to the `phantomjs` binary. You may also want to check the executable permissions on the `phantomjs` binary.

Comment: Hmm that's weird the phantomjs is in the `$PATH` and can be executed in when called from console, but when I did change the js script to have the full path to phantomjs it stopped producing the error. But the Image is still not created. Any idea why??

Comment: If your PHP script is running via Apache, php-fpm, or similar, then the user you're executing it as from the console is most likely not the same user that your PHP script is executing as (e.g. Apache typically uses an `apache` or `www-data` user).

Comment: Yes setting permissions on the folder fixed that issue as well. Thanks :)